# rvest | read_xml claims error where read_html does not

Tags: r, encoding, web-scraping, rvest

Taking the following url

```
URL <- "http://www.google.de/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=TDS38311DE"
doc <- read_xml(URL)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xDF 0x20 0x2F 0x20 [9]
```

Using `read_html` instead everything is fine.
Am i doing something wrong? Why does this error occur?

Comment: The difference is that HTML parsers have built in error correction by default; XML parsers do not. This really is an error: a byte with hex value DF cannot exist on its own in an UTF-8 document. I'm not sure how to solve this; my best guess is to not assume that the page is correct XML.

Comment: So the answer is that google return broken/corrupted xml-responses?

Comment: That seems to be the implication, yes. However, if I download that page, there is no DF in it. The only multibyte sequence is C3 9F, which is correct UTF-8 for ß. However, since ß is U+00DF, I suspect there might be something going wrong between the page itself and the read_xml routine. Is there a conversion to Windows-1252 somewhere? If so, that wouldn't be a problem _if_ the read_xml routine would be told that the encoding is Windows-1252 rather than UTF-8.

Comment: Using `read_xml(URL, encoding = "Windows-1252")` it works perfectly. Thanks! Can you please post this as an answer

Comment: But we're really not solving the problem by doing that, we're only getting rid of the error message. Any XML page that would contain codepoints outside the Windows-1252 range would be either mangled, or cause other errors. I really think you should investigate what causes the conversion to take place.

Comment: I opened a ticket on Github: https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/114

Comment: you solved the issue thanks to encoding guidance by @MrLister. Why open a ticket? this is the correct usage of `read_xml`? also: programmatic access to google search results is a violation of their ToS.

Comment: Ok, now i am confused: Is google giving back not correctly UTF-8 encoded XML-Files or is it a `read_xml`-error? I am really not an expert on encoding. So please excuse my confused-ness.

Comment: @Floo0 I don't know. As far as I can see, Google sends the correct format (the bytes C3 9F), so if read_xml sees a DF instead, there has already been a conversion somewhere. I just can't tell where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `rvest` uses `xml2` for the acquisition of content so you should file any issue relating to it under that package gh vs `rvest`.

Second, `read_xml` *takes* an `encoding` parameter for a reason and *says so*: *"Unless otherwise specified XML documents are assumed to be in UTF-8 or UTF-16. If the document is not UTF-8/16, and lacks an explicit encoding directive, this allows you to supply a default."*

XML files have the ability to [specify an encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EncodingDecl) but this "AJAX-y" response from google clearly isn't (and it's not something it's expecting you to be pilfering and it knows it's being read—usually—by an HTML parsing engine [a.k.a. a browser], not an XML parsing engine).

`rvest` used to do this:

```
encoding <- encoding %||% default_encoding(x)

xml2::read_xml(httr::content(x, "raw"), encoding = encoding, base_url = x$url,
  as_html = as_html)
```

And `default_encoding` does this:

```
default_encoding <- function(x) {
  type <- httr::headers(x)$`Content-Type`
  if (is.null(type)) return(NULL)

  media <- httr::parse_media(type)
  media$params$charset
}
```

but `rvest` now only exposes `read_xml` methods for `session` and `response` objects (where it does the encoding guessing).

So, you can either:

- do some manual introspection prior to scraping (after reading a site's ToS),
- use `httr` to grab a page and pass that to `read_xml`, or
- hook up your own reader function into your script with the same idiom

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This was very helpful. Also pointing out what it "used to do". This is a good start for writing ones one reader function.